Error while using the NextAuth Credentials provider with argon2 in Nextjs App router project
:
I'm using the argon2 package to hash and verify my passwords, and if I use argon2.verify inside the authorize function in auth.config.ts I get the following error:
UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:crypto" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme). Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Here is my auth.config.ts file:
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

import { LoginSchema } from './lib/zod'
import { getUserByEmail } from './utils/db'
import { verifyPassword } from './utils/hash'

export default {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials: Partial<Record<string, unknown>>): Promise<object | null> {
        // Validate the provided credentials against the LoginSchema
        const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials)

        if (!validatedFields.success) {
          return null
        }

        const { email, password } = validatedFields.data
        const user = await getUserByEmail(email)

        if (!user || !user.password) {
          return null
        }
        const passwordsMatch = await verifyPassword(password, user.password)

        if (passwordsMatch) {
          return user
        }

        // if passwords do not match
        return null
      },
    }),
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig

and here is my verifyPassword function:
export const verifyPassword = async (password: string, hash: string): Promise<boolean> => {
  try {
    return await argon2.verify(hash, password)
  } catch {
    throw new Error('Verification failed')
  }
}

I have verified the verifiyPassword function outside the authorize function, and it's working just fine. However it's not working inside authorize. Something like bcrypt works, but I want to use argon2. I have tried @node-rs/argon2 too, but that's not working at all.

instead of wildcard import use specific import
import { verify } from "argon2";


Nothing changed

Can u pls create a reproducible code sample
